# What to use in this SqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SqlDataAdapter that looks something like:

```
("Select prodID, CatalogType, prodName, catID, Integration, ItemProfileCatalogID From ShoppingCart t1 
INNER JOIN ItemCatalogProfile t2 ON t1.CatalogType = t2.CatalogType
WHERE SessionID = '" + Session["ID"] + "' AND CatalogID ='" + Session["Customer"] ....)
```

there are a few more included in the where statement, but the one I cannot seem to get to work is:

```
ItemProfileCatalogID ..
```

I need to include this to narrow down the items down to only one of each and this variable will do just that if I can figure out what to use in this statement.

I've tried

```
viewstate[""]
Request.QuerryString[""]
Session[""]
```

and I cant seem to get those to work..

The problem I am having is, the current shopping cart if I do not have this item to filter, it will return every instance of that particular product in the database because there are up to 250 listings of one item for different catalogs, and that is where the ItemProfileCatalogID comes in, that will filter it down to just the one item

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: What problems are you having? Is it an error message?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but I do know that you should not use string concatenation for creating SQL statements. Especially if they are coming from query strings. See [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @JoeW, you should clarify or else you won't get answers. `ItemProfileCatalogID` belongs to which table? Do you want to use it as filter? Are you trying to determine where the filter value comes from? You gotta give us something...

Comment: Alright Forgot to say what the problem was.. i did an edit, I would like to use that as a filter

Answer (score 1):

`CatalogID` is probably numeric and you are using it as a string in your SQL statement.

It could also be that you have some syntax error in your SQL statement not easily detectable with all the string concatenation going on or due to `CatalogID` containing a naughty character (`'` for example)

Also, please check out [parametrized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688059/what-to-use-in-this-sqldataadapter) queries; concatenation when building SQL statements is usually not a very good idea ([SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

Comment: removed the  ' ' and yes it is numeric, i am now getting: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'  so I am guessing that is coming from that it isn't actually returning anything

Answer (score 1):

As InBetween said it probably is an issue with it being numeric, you should be able to use the .toString() method to solve this.

Also Stored procedures are generaly more advisable to use for a number of reasons, in your case you mentioned you are working with a shopping cart which suggests maybe some kind of ecommerce application? Using a stored procedure here will mean that SQL does not have to compile your select statement every time you run it thus improving performance and having the code in a stored proc will also increase maintainability and possibly allow you to reuse the procedure in other places.

Added to this you are not actually transmitting the select statement over the network which increases security as no one can intercept this and gain insight into your table structures, and as InBetween mentioned above a stored procedure will help you protect against injection attacks or just simply unforseen data as you can add error handling more easily.

Comment: i tried using the .ToString() method, with no success. I would like to get this function working properly first, and once I get that done, I will be more available to focus on creating and implementing a Stored Proc.. do you suggest a ViewState or what should I be using to get the variable?